# Minimal nontrivial coprime action - Kurzweil-Stellmacher Theorem 8.5.2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Kurzweil-Stellmacher Theorem 8.5.2 states:

> Let $A$ be an Abelian $p$-group that acts on the $p$'-group $G$, and set $A_0 := C_A(G)$.  Suppose that $[G,A] \ne 1$, but $[U,A] = 1$ for every $A$-invariant subgroup $U \ne G$.  Then:
>
> (a) $r(A/A_0) = 1$.  [$r(G)$ denotes the minimal size of a generating set for $G$.]
>
> (b) If the semidirect product $AG$ acts on the elementary Abelian $p$-group $V$ such that $C_G(V) = 1$, then $AG/A_0$ acts faithfully on $C_V(A_0)$.

The proof given for (b) is:

> Set $K := C_{AG}(C_V(A_0))$.  The $P \times Q$-Lemma (8.2.8, with $P = A_0$) shows that $K$ is a $p$-group.  As $A_0 \le K$ and $G$ is a $p$'-group, we get that $K=A_0$.

I don't follow the last step of this proof.  After proving that $K$ is a $p$-group, I can only get $A_0 \le K \le A$.  It all seems a little strange because $A_0$ doesn't seem to be related to $V$ in any obvious way.  Why couldn't we have something like $A$ acting trivially on $V$ in which case $C_V(A_0) = V$, but $AG/A_0$ would not be faithful on $V$?

I know, that counterexample does not literally work, because it would be incompatible with the semidirect product action:  If $A$ acts trivially on $V$, then $a^{-1}g = g^a a^{-1}$ implies that the image of every $v \in V$ under both $g$ and $g^a$ are the same, so $g = g^a$ by the $C_G(V) = 1$ assumption.  Thus $[G,A] = 1$ contrary to hypothesis. But how do I complete the argument for (b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K$ is the kernel of the action of $AG$ on $C_V(A_0)$, so $K \unlhd AG$. So $[K,G] \le K \cap G = 1$ (since ($K$ is a $p$-group and $G$ is a $p'$-group). So $K \le C_{AG}(G)$ and hence $K = A_0$.